# Handling Timezones in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, timezone, timezone-offset

I have a need to display the date times according to user selected time zone. So, I am maintaining all date times in database in GMT.

When I am retrieving it from SQL - I am using the following approach (Eg: UK) which I am not sure if it will work for timezones which has Day light saving.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,GetUTCDate()),'-00:00'))
```

During Day Light Saving, it should be

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,GetUTCDate()),'-01:00'))
```

How can I switch the offset according to Day Light Saving? I am saving the user selected Time zone display name ID in the database which I am giving to the second parameter of `SWITCHOFFSET`

Thanks

Comment: In software that is used across multiple time zones I have always let the display layer of the application handle it. The user has a timezone selected in their operating system and .NET, etc. have ways to convert the times more easily than trying to figure it all out in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You would normally let the UI layer or higher abstraction layer handle this. The database and business logic can best work with the UTC time. Otherwise you should take the offset in account in all your business logic which uses the times from the database.

Comment: Yeah. Why do that in SQL - where you need to tell the SQL Server the timezone of the user and program it all yourself - when in reality you have a perfect higher level. This is a front end transformation, do it there.